# Calcular troco e exibir notas disponíveis com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, for, matemática

Estou com uma atividade de aula para fazer, aonde devo receber do usuário o valor da compra e o valor pago, e então exibir o troco. Até aí ok, só que também pede para exibir numa textarea as notas utilizadas no troco, informando sempre o mínimo de notas possíveis, exemplo:

```js
vlrCompra = 53,00
vlrPago = 100,00
vlrTroco = 47,00 

notasTroco = 
4 notas de 10,00
1 nota   de  5,00
2 notas  de  1,00
```

Não tenho ideia de como fazer essa última parte, alguém para me ajudar?
**AS NOTAS QUE EU TENHO DISPONIVEIS SAO 1, 5, 10, 50**

Eis o que fiz até agora:

```
function calculaTroco(){

    var valorCompra = parseFloat($("#valorCompra").val());
    var valorPago = parseFloat($("#valorPago").val());
    var valorTroco = 0;


    if (valorPago == valorCompra){
        valorTroco = 0;
        $("#valorTroco").val(valorTroco);
        alert("Não gerou troco");

    }else if(valorPago > valorCompra){

        valorTroco = valorPago - valorCompra;
        $("#valorTroco").val(valorTroco);

    }else{
        alert("Não gerou troco (Valor pago menor que valor da compra)");
    }

    $("#valorCompra").val("");
    $("#valorPago").val("");
    $("#valorCompra").focus();
}
```

Lembrando que preciso fazer esta parte das notas em outra function, até agora já aprendemos array, for...

Parte do HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Calcular Troco</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="formulario">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Calcular Troco</legend>

                <label for="valorCompra" >Valor da compra:</label>
                <input type="text" id="valorCompra" name="valorCompra" /><br />

                <label for="valorPago" >Valor pago:</label>
                <input type="text" id="valorPago" name="valorPago" /><br /><br />

                <button type="button" id="button" onclick="calculaTroco()">Calcular troco</button><br /><br />

                <label for="valorTroco" >Valor do troco:</label>
                <input type="text" id="valorTroco" name="valorTroco" readonly="readonly"/><br /><br />  

                <label for="notasUtilizadas">Notas utilizadas:</label>
                <textarea rows="3" id="notasUtilizadas" readonly="readonly" ></textarea><br/>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="troco.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não vou fazer o seu exercício por você, mas você precisará entender sobre [resto de divisão](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#M%C3%B3dulo_()) e divisão inteira (você pode [truncar](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) uma divisão normal) para solucionar seu problema.

Comment: fernandosavio poderia me dar mais dicas para eu conseguir fazer o exercício? Vou precisar utilizar arrays?

Comment: Você até pode utilizar arrays, mas não faz parte do seu problema central. Você precisa aprender para que serve a divisão e o seu resto. Você precisa entender como você descobre quantos X cabem dentro de tantos Y...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma função própria para calcular as notas e utilize uma array com os valores em ordem decrescente:

```
var notas = [50,10,5,1];
```

Envie para a função o valor do troco e faça um loop na array deduzindo o valor do troco pela divisão do número de notas x o valor da nota da array, criando uma string com as informações que será enviada para o textarea. No final a função irá retornar a string com a quantidade certa de notas.

Veja:

```js
function calculaTroco(){

    var valorCompra = parseFloat($("#valorCompra").val());
    var valorPago = parseFloat($("#valorPago").val());
    var valorTroco = 0;
    
    if (valorPago == valorCompra){
        valorTroco = 0;
        $("#valorTroco").val(valorTroco);
        alert("Não gerou troco");

    }else if(valorPago > valorCompra){

        valorTroco = valorPago - valorCompra;
        $("#valorTroco").val(valorTroco);
        
        // envia para o textarea o retorno da função calculaNotas
        $("#notasUtilizadas").val(calculaNotas(valorTroco));

    }else{
        alert("Não gerou troco (Valor pago menor que valor da compra)");
    }

    $("#valorCompra").val("");
    $("#valorPago").val("");
    $("#valorCompra").focus();

}

// função para calcular as notas
function calculaNotas(troco){
   var notas = [50,10,5,1];
   var texto = '';
   for(var x=0; x < notas.length; x++){
      if(troco >= notas[x]){
         var div = Math.floor(troco/notas[x]);
         texto += div + " notas de "+notas[x]+"\n";
         troco -= div*notas[x];
      }
      
   }
   return texto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Calcular Troco</legend>

       <label for="valorCompra" >Valor da compra:</label>
       <input type="text" id="valorCompra" name="valorCompra" /><br />

       <label for="valorPago" >Valor pago:</label>
       <input type="text" id="valorPago" name="valorPago" /><br /><br />

       <button type="button" id="button" onclick="calculaTroco()">Calcular troco</button><br /><br />

       <label for="valorTroco" >Valor do troco:</label>
       <input type="text" id="valorTroco" name="valorTroco" readonly/><br /><br />  

       <label for="notasUtilizadas">Notas utilizadas:</label>
       <textarea rows="3" id="notasUtilizadas" readonly ></textarea><br/>

   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Divisão é uma operação MUITO custosa e não é necessária, basta ir diminuindo o valor da nota do troco e só incrementar o índice do array de notas quando a nota atual for maior do que o troco. Ver a resposta do user156436.

Comment: Posso até concordar que o modo que o outro amigo fez é bem mais prático, mas no contexto do código do AP irá dar um certo trabalho para montar o texto dentro do textarea :D

Comment: Sam muito obrigada, me ajudou muito

Comment: @user156424 De nada, amiga. Veja como agradecer no [tour]. Abs!

Answer (score 6):

Esse é um exemplo de como iterar sobre um array de notas, e utilizar associação para armazenar a quantidade de cada uma. Deixo a manipulação desse resultado com você.

```js
function gerarTroco(valor) {
  // Notas disponíveis
  var notas = [50, 10, 5, 1]
  // Troco é um objeto, associando notas com a quantidade necessária
  var troco = {'50': 0, '10': 0, '5': 0, '1': 0}
  
  // Itero sobre o array de notas
  for (var nota of notas) {
    // Se o valor restante for maior que minha nota atual..
    while (valor >= nota) {
      // incremento a propriedade do objeto correspondente a nota
      troco[nota] += 1
      // e reduzo o valor restante pelo valor da nota
      valor -= nota
    }
  }

  return troco
}

console.log('Troco para 58:', gerarTroco(58))
```

Comment: muito obrigada pela ajuda user156436

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz uma vez usando o node, que funcionou muito bem!

```js
function sacarDinheiro(valorSaque) {
    let contador100 = 0
    let contador50 = 0
    let contador10 = 0
    let contador5 = 0
    let contador1 = 0
    let valorNota = calcularValorNota(valorSaque)
    while (valorSaque >= valorNota) {
        switch (valorNota) {
            case 100:
                valorSaque -= 100
                contador100++
                break
            case 50:
                valorSaque -= 50
                contador50++
                break
            case 10:
                valorSaque -= 10
                contador10++
                break
            case 5:
                valorSaque -= 5
                contador5++
                break
            case 1:
                contador1++
                valorSaque -= 1
                break
        }

        valorNota = calcularValorNota(valorSaque)

    }
    return elaborarResultado(contador100, contador50, contador10, contador5, contador1)
}

function calcularValorNota(valorSaque) {
    if (valorSaque >= 100) {
        return 100
    } else if (valorSaque >= 50) {
        return 50
    } else if (valorSaque >= 10) {
        return 10
    } else if (valorSaque >= 5) {
        return 5
    } else if (valorSaque >= 1) {
        return 1
    }
}

function elaborarResultado(contador100, contador50, contador10, contador5, contador1) {
    let resultado = ''

    if (contador100 > 0) {
        resultado += `${contador100} nota(s) de R$ 100. `
    }

    if (contador50 > 0) {
        resultado += `${contador50} nota(s) de R$ 50. `
    }

    if (contador10 > 0) {
        resultado += `${contador10} nota(s) de R$ 10. `
    }

    if (contador5 > 0) {
        resultado += `${contador5} nota(s) de R$ 5. `
    }

    if (contador1 > 0) {
        resultado += `${contador1} nota(s) de R$ 1. `
    }

    return resultado
}

console.log(sacarDinheiro(47))
console.log(sacarDinheiro(298));
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos começar o algorítimo com um pseudocódigo.

Segue o problema:

- Dado uma compra que possui um **total** e um **valorPago**.
- Calcular o **troco**.
- Calcular a quantidade de **Cédulas** ou **Moedas** com base no **troco**.

Organizando o código:

`troco = ValorPago - total`

Devemos verificar se o `valorPago` é **menor** que o `total`

**SE** `ValorPago < Total` **ENTÃO** EXIBIR MENSAGEM DE ERRO.

Ok, agora já temos o valor do troco. Basta seguir para o cálculo de cédulas/moedas.

Vamos fornecer uma lista de Cédulas/Moedas para nosso cáculo.

`cedulasMoedas = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.05]`

Com esses valores fornecidos, devemos:

- Definir uma variável que irá conter o **resto**
- Interar por cada item da lista
- Dividir o **resto** pelo valor da lista: `resto / valor`
- Verificar se o resultado é maior ou igual a 1.
- Se a condição for verdadeira, o valor da divisão é a quantidade de notas, e
  o resto da divisão será atribuido a variável para o próximo cálculo.

Passando para javascript:

```js
const cedulasMoedas = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.05];
const resultado = [];
const total = 256.55;
const totalPago = 300;

if (totalPago < total) {
  throw new Error("Valor pago é menor que o total");
}

// Calculamos o troco e delimitamos para apenas 2 casas decimais
const troco = +(totalPago - total).toFixed(2);

// Precisamos declarar uma variável para conter o resto da conta.
let resto = troco;

for (let valor of cedulasMoedas) {

  // Usamos o Math.floor para pegar somente o menor número inteiro. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor
  const quantidade = Math.floor(resto / valor);

  // Adicionamos essa condição para que quando o resultado for igual a zero ele ignore o script e passe para o próximo valor
  if (quantidade === 0) continue; 

  // Adicionamos os valores na lista
  resultado.push({ quantidade, valor });
  
  // Atribuimos o resto da divisão ao troco para o próximo cálculo
  resto = resto % valor;
  
}

console.log({troco, resultado});
```